# Load large static set of ids once with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of 100K user ids in a static file.  In my application, every time I get a request, I want to check if the user id is in the list of ids.  So I want to read the file into a set when Rails first boots, and then refer to the set instance across multiple requests.  What would be the proper way to implement something like this in Rails?

Comment: You said the file doesn't change? Why not just load it into the db once and for all?

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing.  But seems like it would be faster and simpler to return from an in memory object, so I'm still wondering how to do this.

Comment: You can use an in-memory db like redis. Though depending on your actual usage the performance gain might not make a real difference.

Comment: Insert all ids in static to database, then add index for column id. You can search a user id in table super fast. It's also easy for CRUD list of user ids.